# How to run supervisor with Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, supervisord

I've got a server on which [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) is managing my processes. I normally start supervisord with the following command:

```
sudo /var/www/imd/venv/bin/supervisord -c /var/www/imd/deploy/supervisord.conf
```

I'm now trying to set things up with [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), but I'm unsure of how I should start Ansible. I can of course do it using something like:

```
- name: run supervisord
  command: "/var/www/imd/venv/bin/supervisord -c /var/www/imd/deploy/supervisord.conf"
```

This works, but only the first time that you run it. Second time you run the same script supervisord is of course already running, which causes the following error:

> TASK [run supervisord]
>   ******************************************************* fatal: [ansible-test1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd":
>   ["/var/www/imd/venv/bin/supervisord", "-c",
>   "/var/www/imd/deploy/supervisord.conf"], "delta": "0:00:00.111700",
>   "end": "2016-06-03 11:57:38.605804", "failed": true, "rc": 2, "start":
>   "2016-06-03 11:57:38.494104", "stderr": "Error: Another program is
>   already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured
>   to use.  Shut this program down first before starting
>   supervisord.\nFor help, use /var/www/imd/venv/bin/supervisord -h",
>   "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

Does anybody know how I can correctly run supervisord with Ansible? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

Because the solution in the answer by mbarthelemy doesn't work for socket files I now managed to get it working with the following:

```
- name: run supervisord
  shell: if [ ! -S /var/run/supervisor.sock ]; then sudo /var/www/imd/venv/bin/supervisord -c /var/www/imd/deploy/supervisord.conf; fi
```

This of course is not very "ansibleish". If anybody has a real Ansible-based solution that would still be really welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use supervisor module

```
- supervisorctl:
    name: my_app
    state: restarted
    config: /var/opt/my_project/supervisord.conf
```

or

```
 - name: Restart my_app
   supervisorctl:
     name: my_app
     state: restarted
     config: /var/opt/my_project/supervisord.conf
```

full documentation on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/supervisorctl_module.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is specific since you don't seem to use a regular Supervisor installed as a normal system package ; in that case you would start/stop/restart it like any other regular system service, using Ansible's `service` module.

By default, upon starting Supervisor creates a socket to listen for administrations commands from `supervisorctl`. When it stops it it supposed to remove it.

Try to find where this socket is created in your specific setup (default would be `/var/run/supervisor.sock`).
Then, let the Ansible `command` module know that if the Suopervisord process is already running, the socket exists, using the `creates` option ([documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html)). This way it won't try to run the `command` if it's already running:

```
- name: run supervisord
  command: "./venv/bin/supervisord -c ./deploy/supervisord.conf"
  args: 
    chdir=/var/www/imd
    creates=/var/run/supervisor.sock
```

**Edit** : while this would be the right answer if `/var/run/supervisor.sock` were a file, it won't work because it's a socket, and Ansible's `create` parameter won't work.

The most Ansible-ish solution I can think of is using an external Ansible module like one of these, to check if you process already exists (`test_process`) or is already listening (`test_tcp`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to recognise that `/var/run/supervisor.sock` has already been created. I checked if it exists (it does exist), but it seems to still try to start supervisor because I get the same error saying `"Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use"`. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Alright, I checked if the file exists with a regular `if [ ! -f /var/run/supervisor.sock ]; then echo 'file does not exist!'; fi`, and that also says the file doesn't exist. That is because the `-f` flag only reports on regular files, where I need the `-S` flag for socket files. Could it be that the test that Ansible does also only goes for regular files? Is there a way that I can select the file type for `creates`, or are there any other options?